# Cocoa - NSTabViewController, how to change tabview on button press?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstabview, nstabviewcontroller

I've spent the past few days trying to work this out. Basically, when a user presses a button in my first tab, I want the the tabview to change to the next tab.

[Here's how my storyboard looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZu4A.png). More specifically, when a user presses Youtube in my Homepage tab, I want FirstWebController to open.

Every method Ive found online hasn't worked, so I was hoping someone could provide some insight into next step I should take.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `NSTabViewController`'s `selectedTabViewItemIndex` to the index of the tab item you want to select and it will change. You do have to keep track of the positions of the tab view items so you know which index is which but that's really only something you have to worry about if your tab view items are dynamic.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but after doing this my index is always at -1. Looking at my storyboard, Im not sure if its set up correctly. https://imgur.com/ivLISp3, is that how its meant to be set up?

Comment: Any chance you could share the project? Happy to take a quick look and make sure it's all wired up correctly.

Comment: Yes that would be great if you could. I have a feeling the issue is simple but I can't get past it. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/9gnq1w64xg3l9u0/AACumttvsV40Vgdj0UIu3W2Va?dl=0

Comment: Okay, I was able to get this behavior by adding the following code to favLabel1:

`NSTabViewController *tabVC = (NSTabViewController*)[self parentViewController];`
`tabVC.selectedTabViewItemIndex = 1;`

With that in place, clicking YouTube changes the tab to the second tab in the NSTabViewController.

Comment: Wow thanks thats exactly what I needed. Cheers for all the help you've saved me a great deal of head scratching.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
```

Delegate method to track when tabbar Item tapped and can set index there.